# How to retrieve a single row as a string from a database and compare it to another string in a textbox?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, tableadapter

I am brand new to relational database manipulation with Visual C# as well as posting to StackOverflow. I have done every tutorial and read every word in the chapter on databases in Tony Gaddis' book Starting Out With Visual C#. As well as hours of googling and wading through walls of text and 20 minute tutorial videos.

I have created a database, connected it to the project and created a login form. All without a single line of code being written on my part.(The magic of "Visual" C#, eh?). The database has a table called Login with attributes called Email and Password. I am now trying to check the database for the Password WHERE Email is equal to the contents of the "Username" textbox and then compare those results to the contents of the "Password" textbox

This is my code for the Login button which I want to do what I described above:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.MaintenanceTableAdapter.GetPasswordByEmail(this.MaintenanceDataSet.Login, txtUsername.Text) == txtPassword.Text)
            {
                Main main = new Main();
                main.Show();
            }
        }
```

GetPassWordByEmail is a method for a query I made in the MaintenanceDataSet.xsd file page. It asks for the row containing the Password where the Email column corresponds to the contents of a textbox called txtUsername.

I am getting errors under "MaintenanceTableAdapter" and "MaintenanceDataSet." I find this odd because in the tutorials when I would drag a DataGridView onto a form and then go over to the code I could use "TutorialTableAdapter" and "TutorialDataSet" to run queries just fine.

I'm very confused with all the talk I found while googling about TableAdapters and BindingSources so if you could explain like I'm 5 how those relate to what I'm doing here I'd be much obliged.
In fact if you could explain any part of this as if I were 5 that'd be great too:)

tl;dr do you know how I can query a database in C# to return a single row as a string and then compare that string to another string?

I will provide any more information you might need upon request. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am getting errors under "MaintenanceTableAdapter" and "MaintenanceDataSet." --what error did you get?

Comment: The form does not contain a definition for MaintenanceTableAdapter

Comment: Well, then clearly the current form (that you're referencing using `this`) does not have access to `MaintenanceTableAdapter`. Where is `MaintenanceTableAdapter` declared and created? It's not on your login form where the code you've posted is located.

Comment: I talked to my teacher and he said he thinks that in VS 2013 there isn't a way to make a TableAdapter "visually" per se, they are automatically generated when you drag a DataGridView with a tables contents onto a form, and it won't work the way I am trying to do it. All that to say: I have to write every query in code with a database connection that I establish in a static class, because there is no way I can just use tableAdapter methods if I can't make a tableAdapter.